# Uncaught TypeError: this.submitData is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have defined a async function in methods and when trying to call the same function in mounted.. it is giving the error  - Uncaught TypeError: this.submitData is not a function.
Please help me out how to call async function in mounted() in **vue js**. Below is my code -

```
<template>
    <section class="section-b-space">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 category-side col-md-4">
                    <div class="category-option">
                        <div class="accordion category-name" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="accordion-item category-price">
                                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingFour">
                                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-bs-target="#collapseFour">Price</button>
                                </h2>
                                <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                                    aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="accordion-body">
                                        <div class="range-slider category-list">
                                            <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" id="js-range-price" value="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-item category-rating">
                                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-bs-target="#collapseSix">
                                        Category
                                    </button>
                                </h2>
                                <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                                    aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                    <div class="accordion-body category-scroll">
                                        <ul class="category-list">
                                            <li v-for="category in categories">
                                                <div class="form-check ps-0 custome-form-check">
                                                    <input class="checkbox_animated check-it" 
                                                        type="checkbox" @change="submitData" v-model="formData.category">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label">{{category.name}}</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
    export default{
        props:{
            categories: {
                default: []
            },
        },
        data(){
            return {
                formData:{
                    category: [],
                    price: '',
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async submitData(){
                try{
                    const response = await axios.post('/api/category', this.formData)
                    console.log(response);
                }
                catch(error){
                    console.log(error)
                }
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function(){
                this.submitData()
                    .then((res)=>{
                        console.log(res);
                })
                    .catch((err)=>{
                        console.log(err);
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is .vue file and i am using vue3

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. There's no [tag:jquery] above, nor [tag:node.js], and although you're using [tag:axios], there's no reason to believe it's related to the problem.

Comment: can you share some more details

Comment: I want to call `submitData()` in `mounted()`, but it is not accessible. Same function if i call input box, then it is accessible. i don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: What is the file name of the file containing the above code? Can you provide some code related to how you are calling it from another component?

Comment: which version of vue is this? vue2 or vue3? - not sure it makes a difference, but it seems to work fine in vue3

Comment: I have updated the code and i am using vue3..please review.. When i call the same function in checkbox it's working, but not working in `mounted()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following lines:

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function() {
    this.submitData()
      .then((res)=>{
         console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}
```

We can see that you've attached a listener to the 'change' event to an element with the `js-range-slider` class using a callback defined with `function`.

An important thing to note here is that when using `function() { }`, the callback will have its `this` value set to the element on which the listener was attached (so you can use things like `this.value` to get the current value).

To maintain access to the `this` from `mounted()`, which is your initialized component, you can do one of the following:

1. Change to an arrow function for your callback:

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function() {
    this.submitData()
```

becomes

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', () => {
    this.submitData() // `this` is inherited from `mounted()`
```

2. Store the `this` from `mounted()` and use that value instead:

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function() {
    this.submitData()
```

becomes

```
mounted() {
  const instance = this;
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function() {
    instance.submitData()
```

3. Store the `this` from `mounted()` into the event's data by passing it in as the second argument to `on()`:

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', function() {
    this.submitData()
```

becomes

```
mounted() {
  $(".js-range-slider").on('change', { component: this }, function(event) {
    event.data.component.submitData()
```